# TypoScript HMENU to display page columns in TYPO3

Tags: menu, typo3, submenu, typoscript

I've been on this for a while now, but still unable to find a proper solution.

I have three root pages `Root, SuperSub1 and Sub_1`. The pages `Root and SuperSub1` have many other sub pages and page `Sub_2` has content in column position 2.

My aim is to display a menu like this:

```
Root
--SuperSub1
--SuperSub2
--SuperSub3
```

clicking on `SuperSub1`

```
Root
--SuperSub1
----Sub1
----Sub2
--SuperSub2
--SuperSub3
```

clicking on `Sub1`

```
    Root
    --SuperSub1
    ----Sub1
            // Display Page Content of Sub1 page where column position = 2
            // The content will contain header, text and images
    ----Sub2
```

My Typoscript so far is as follows:

```
lib.level2Menu = HMENU
lib.level2Menu.entryLevel=1
lib.level2Menu.1 = TMENU
lib.level2Menu.1

lib.level2Menu{
    1{
    wrap = <ul class="submenus_level2">|</ul>
    expAll = 0
    NO.allWrap = <li><span class="category_name">|</span></li>
    RO < .NO
    RO = 1
    CUR < .NO
    CUR = 1
    CUR.allWrap = <li><span class="category_name">|</span></li>
    ACT < .CUR
    }

    2 <.1
    2.expAll = 1
    2.wrap =  <div class="submenu">|</div>
    2.sectionIndex = 1
    2.sectionIndex.useColPos = 2
}
```

The script does not render what I want, it displays only the header of the content (if present) and wraps itself in the tags of the parent menu.

**EDIT**

OR can I give a `div` holder in the Typoscript and later fill it in my FLUID template. Like this:

```
    NO.allWrap = <li><span class="category_name">|</span></li><div class="subpagecontent"> #Define something here  </div>
```

and later in my Fluid I can fill the div as

```
<div class="subpagecontent"> {myPageContentWithCol2}  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be something like a megadropdown, right?

What I do there is hardcode the "Supersub" Page uids  -  each "Supersub" is its own HMENU in a COA. Then you are free to build the content of the second "Supersub" from tt_content.

It's a bit ugly, but as there are only a few 2nd level items, it's acceptable, I think.